# Как сказать линкеру какую либу линковать: SO/DLL или A/LIB?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, ld

Подскажите, я сбилдил библиотеку. В `lib` каталоге лежат и `*.a` и `*.so`. Я пытаюсь каким-либо образом сказать `CMake`у, что нужно линковать со статическими (или наоборот, не суть). Думал через `target_link_options` и `target_compile_options` передать какой-нибудь флаг, но не могу нагуглить ничего толкового. Нашел флаги `-static` и `-shared`, но они для билда самой либы, а не линковки с внешней. **Как быть?** Да, если что, делаю это через `pkg-config`.

**Для примера:**

```
ImageMagick_LDFLAGS:
-L/opt/ImageMagick-7.0.11.10/lib;-lMagick++-7.Q16HDRI;-lMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI;-lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI
```

Видно, что либки передаются без указания `STATIC/SHARED`...

Comment: `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: @eanmos, и что с ней делать? Она итак используется. Но там нет никаких парамтеров для этого.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754160/cmake-target-link-libraries-use-static-library-not-shared

Comment: С dll/lib все просто - dll в линковке не используются.

Comment: @Croessmah, спасибо. Заглянул в `FindPkgConfig.cmake`, функция `pkg_check_modules` использует `find_library`, следовательно `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES` на неё по идее тоже должен распространяться. Будем экспериментировать.